# Среда выдает следующую ошибку: expected primary-expression before 'char' в предпоследней строке. Что делать?

Tags: c++, функции

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

void Draw(char (&M)[20][10])
    {
        system("cls");
        for (int i=0; i < 20; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                if (i==0 || j==0 || j==9 || i==19)
                    M[i][j] = '#';
                cout <<  M[i][j];
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
    }
int main()
    {
        char M [20][10] = {0};
        while (true)
            Draw(char M[20][10]);
        return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызывать в `main` просто

```
Draw(M);
```

Но у вас не видно этого массива. Конечно, вы должны его создать, прежде чем передавать в функцию. Как я вижу, вы его уже создали в исправленном вопросе.

И еще непоняно - вы хотите вызывать эту функцию в цикле вечно?

Comment: Нет, так как уже есть system("cls").

Comment: У вас цикл `while(true)` - он будет выполняться вечно.